# How to add data using request body

Tags: java, json, post, request

Hello I've got a task to add a book to the store. I've got action like this:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String addBook(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam String isbn, @RequestParam String title,
                      @RequestParam String author, @RequestParam String publisher, @RequestParam String type) {
    memoryBookService.addBook(new Book(id,isbn,title,author,publisher,type));
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

But instead of adding the book that way I am supposed to use something like this below. The issue is that i dont know how to pass parameteres from post method to my constructor to add new book using this RequestBody. Can someone explain this to me?

```
 @PostMapping("/")
public String addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
// code
    return "redirect:/";
```

This is my JSON:

```
      {"id": "1L" 
      "isbn": "9788324631766"
      "title": "Thinking in Java"  
      "author": "Bruce Eckel"
      "publisher": "Helion"
      "type": "programming"
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jersey or any framework that you are using is doing the heavy lifting for you to create a Book object from the input json. Once you have got your deserialized object in form of Book object, you can just use getters to fetch the id, isbn and other information

```
book.getId()
book.getIsbn()
```

However, you can either use POSTMAN or cURL to send the json to your service.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id": "1L", "isbn": "9788324631766","title": "Thinking in Java","author": "Bruce Eckel","publisher": "Helion", "type": "programming" }' http://localhost:8080/<servicename>
```